# Parsing XML from a table column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table containing a column title Data that is XML. I need to extract a field from that column so I can use it to join to another table. The trouble I am running into is when I set the XML variable because there are many rows of XML I need the field from. Here's my query so far:

```
declare @XML as XML
set @XML = (select [Data] from tbl.api.Session where applicationid 
= 25)

select u.n.value('./@username', 'varchar(max)') as username
from @XML.nodes('/ISession/WorkbenchIdentity') as u (n)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if you need any other info.

XML Code:

```
<ISession>
  <ad xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <adSessionGuid>ba07909a-46d3-4f79-a1b2-df4d267f66d5</adSessionGuid>
  </ad>
  <client-info xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <client-browser>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; 
     WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET 
     CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)</client- 
     browser>
    <client-host-ip>172.16.108.8</client-host-ip>
    <res-width>0</res-width>
    <res-height>0</res-height>
  </client-info>
  <guest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <identity xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id>c5a4ff78-fb49-4433-a9a1-d58b766100fb</id>
    <anonymous>false</anonymous>
    <lastAuthenticated>2018-09-15T00:05:48.3436442Z</lastAuthenticated>
    <guest>false</guest>
    <isTestSession>false</isTestSession>
  </identity>
  <WorkbenchIdentity xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id>34193</id>
    <userId>c5a4ff78-fb49-4433-a9a1-d58b766100fb</userId>
    <userName>kwhittington250</userName>
    <lastAuthenticated>2018-09-15T00:05:48.3592653Z</lastAuthenticated>
    <storeId>5898</storeId>
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS -SQL Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work

```
select u.n.value('userName[1]','varchar(max)') as username
from tbl.api.Session s
    cross apply [Data].nodes('/ISession/WorkbenchIdentity') as u(n)
where applicationid = 25
```

I think the `[Data]` field will need to already be the XML data type, though. If it isn't, you might have to replace `tbl.api.Session` with a CTE or suquery that casts the `[Data]` field as XML

Comment: That query is returning NULLs for me, but it's possible that I'm not identifying the nodes correctly. I have included an example of the XML in my original question above, with userName being towards the bottom

Comment: great, thanks. i edited my answer above. also note i did have to fix some of the xml you provided, but i'm assuming that was just a copy-paste / formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore XML variable part, if you have multiple rows then it might fail and return error. You can directly query table and use that to join to other table.

Ex (Assuming Data field is XML datatype):

```
--To return XML values:
SELECT  u.n.value('./@username', 'varchar(max)') as username
from tbl.api.Session s 
outer apply s.Data.nodes('/ISession/WorkbenchIdentity') as u (n)
where applicationid = 25

--To join two tables:
;WITH XML_DATA AS
(
SELECT  u.n.value('./@username', 'varchar(max)') as username
from tbl.api.Session s 
outer apply s.Data.nodes('/ISession/WorkbenchIdentity') as u (n)
where applicationid = 25
)
SELECT A.* FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN XML_DATA B ON A.username = B.username
```